# Why won't IsChecked change on this toggle button?

Tags: wpf, togglebutton, ischecked

I have the following xaml for a toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="0,3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectAllCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
  <ToggleButton.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
       <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select All"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select None"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectNoneCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

But the `IsChecked` property never gets updated when clicking the button.

If I use snoop and force the IsChecked to True then the trigger kicks in.

Comment: What does your Command do?  If I remove your Commands (and just set the Content properties, it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried your ToggleButton and it's working fine. The only problem I see with it is that you set Command explictly. It should be done with a `Setter` instead (like you did with `Content`) to not break the `Trigger`.

```
<ToggleButton Name="toggleButton" Margin="0,3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select All"/>
            <Setter Property="Command"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectAllCommand,
                                    Mode=OneWay,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select None"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectNoneCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

If you're still unable to Click it, I'd check if `IsHitTestVisible` or similar is set to `False` further up the Visual Tree.

If you want to compare your version to my test app to see what's not working, I uploaded it here: http://www.mediafire.com/?ik24ftsfw2wwfwb

Comment: argh, cant access - company firewall blocked it! Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by parameterising my command, binding to a new property on my viewmodel and moving Command into the style:

```
               <ToggleButton Margin="0,3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsThreeState="False" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select All"/>
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.SelectAllCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>                                
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Select None"/>                                
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
```

Don't you just love WPF sometimes!

Comment: WPF IS AWESOME!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but remove the Binding `Mode=OneWay` and try again.

Comment: thanks but no luck.. Do I need to bind something to the IsChecked property to get this working?